# Is the AR-characteristic polynomial independent of the ARMA equations?

Tags: time-series, arima, augmented-dickey-fuller

Say that I begin with a time series $X_t$, and say that it satisfies two different ARMA equations:

$$\Phi_1(B)X_t=\Theta_1(B)Z_t$$
and also
$$\Phi_2(B)X_t=\Theta_2(B)Z_t.$$
Then must $\Phi_1=\Phi_2$? How about if we further require that the degree of $\Phi_1$ be the same as the degree of $\Phi_2$?

The reason that I am asking is that the augmented Dickey Fuller test checks "whether the AR-characteristic polynomial has a unit root". But does that even mean, if the AR-characteristic polynomial is not invariant of the ARMA equations?

Comment: Related post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304975/why-does-an-augmented-dickey-fuller-test-apply-in-an-arma-situation-when-it-s).

Answer (score 1):

There are three fundamental representations of time series: autocovariance function, Wold's MA(∞) and spectral density. If one of the aforementioned representations for two series is the same, then they are the same series.

Try representing your series as MA(∞) and from there you should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: An autocovariance function is sufficient to determine the time-series?! That sounds like a statement that is too strong to be true. Covariance is a very weak invariant -- dependent variables can have 0 covariance.

Comment: Also, since I am not assume the ARMAs I am beginning with are causal, there isn't an MA($\infty$) presentation, only one that goes both backward and forward.

Comment: Please refer to Cochrane's [Time Series for Macroeconomics and Finance](http://econ.lse.ac.uk/staff/wdenhaan/teach/cochrane.pdf), page 26.

Comment: Oh, okay, so that further assumes that the $Z_t$'s are iid Gaussian.

Comment: And again, in the situation of my question, there may not be an MA($\infty$) presentation.